# Why are there two different ways to create functions in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function

In my code I have the following:

```
var setTheme = function (color) {

};

function setTheme(color) {

};
```

The function names are not really the same but I have put the same here. Is there a difference in the two ways of creating a function?

Comment: have a look at it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname

Comment: The first method is often used as callback functions. This is mainly to control the order of function execution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a difference. With a function definition, the entire definition is hoisted:

```
foo(5); // Pops up 5

function foo(n) {
    alert(n);
}
```

Whereas with `var`, the declaration is hoisted but the assignment is not:

```
foo(5); // Error!

var foo = function(n) {
    alert(n);
};
```

Another difference I noticed is that on Google Chrome Canary (currently and at least, I haven't tried in many other browsers) in ECMAScript 5 strict mode, a function definition cannot be nested more than one level deep:

```
!function() {
    'use strict';

    function Blah() {
        function Lol() { // Error.
        }
    }
}();
```

Answer (score 1):

**So,**

*JS function for get set*

```
    var setTheme = function (color) {

    };
```

If you need a private utility for getting/setting/deleting model values then you can declare a function as a variable like this. This could be useful for assigning a variable upon declaration calculated by a function.

**For:** *simple version*

```
function setTheme(color) {

};
```

This is the simplest way to declare a function in JavaScript. Say for example, we want to write a simple function called `setTheme(color)` which simply takes in one parameter `color`, does a simple `color` on the object or returns the value. Here are a few ways you might go about doing exactly this.

***5 Different ways: interesting read:***

http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/5-ways-declare-functions-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered many times. There are many ways to call these. As I understand, the first one is a **function assignment**, the second one is a **function declaration**. The first one will hoist `setTheme` to the top of the closest scope but it won't be defined as a function till it gets where it's actually assigned. The second one will hoist the function `setTheme` up top so you'll be able to use this function even before it's been declared. IMO, use always the first one.